# Does every DAG have at most one "universal source"?

Tags: graphs, directed-graphs

A "universal source" in a directed graph is a vertex v for which out-deg(v)=n-1 and in-deg(v)=0.
I know that any DAG has at least one source but can it have more than one for a universal?
I know there can be none, and there can be one (binary tree for example, root is universal source) but can there be two?

Comment: Assume it has two. Give them names. Consider the relation between these vertices, if any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose towards a contradiction that a DAG $G=(V,E)$ on $n$ vertices has more than one universal source and let $u,v \in V$ be two distinct universal sources of $G$.

Since $\mbox{out-deg}(u)=n-1$, and $G$ contains no self-loops, vertex $u$ has edges towards every other vertex in $G$. In particular $(u,v) \in E$. As a consequence $\mbox{in-deg}(v) \ge 1 > 0$ showing that $v$ cannot be a universal source.